# I don't have access to chat

Tags: support, bug, chat

Since a few month ago, I don't have access to chat.stackoverflow.com.

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.

I don't know why, because there is no message about chat blocking.

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

my question marked as duplicate by Bhargav Rao

I checked [Oops! Something Bad Happened in chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343124/oops-something-bad-happened-in-chat) and all other same question before creating this thread

same question has no any answer and I check last comments

[image]

Is there any guide in same question to help me?

Comment: Huh. I'm getting the same error when I open your chat profile. You've posted here now, so I guess you'll just have to wait.

Comment: Did you merge accounts around that time?  IIRC this has happened before at that was the cause

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes I did, but i didn't block for access to chat  before too

Comment: So the possible issue is that your chat main account is still the old account

Comment: BoltClock's report would point towards that @Redo.

Comment: From tracing back through the user histories, what looks to be the case was that you had an original account, you created a second account to act as a voting sock puppet for that first account, a moderator deleted that second account, you recreated that account with the same credentials, and then you merged this new account with your original. Your chat account was associated with the puppet account and became reattached to your new account when you recreated it with the same credentials, then that transferred to your overall account when those were merged. This somewhat confused the system.

Comment: @BradLarson clearly this user needs to be able to chat with his sock puppet, in order to coordinate their voting rings.

Comment: tl;dr do _not_ cheat on SO.